# How to get AngularJS to respond to navigation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, hyperlink, routes

I am designing a site which has a fixed data set (17 records - each representing a 'book' for sale) and allows navigation between several pages that display details about each of the books.  The problem I am having is that when the hyperlink goes to a different view, everything works fine, but if it is hyperlink is to a different book of the same view, it fails to run the controller script.  How do I force this to be done.

I have made a minimal executable example:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   var fooApp = angular.module('fooApp', []);
   fooApp.controller('fooCtrl', function ($scope) {
       $scope.books = ["Book1", "Book2", "Book3", "Book4", "Book5"]
       $scope.selectedBook = "Book1";
       var curPath = window.location.toString();
       var hashPos = curPath.indexOf("#/");
       if (hashPos>0) {
           $scope.selectedBook = curPath.substring(hashPos+2);
       }
   });
</script>
</head>

<body ng-app="fooApp" ng-controller="fooCtrl">

Selected Book: {{selectedBook}}

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="book in books">Visit A <a href="PageA.htm#/{{book}}">{{book}}</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="book in books">Visit B <a href="PageB.htm#/{{book}}">{{book}}</a>
</li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

Save the above to two different files: PageA.htm and also as PageB.htm.  The selected book is passed as a parameter after the hash mark.  You will see the behavior as this:  When on PageA you can click on a link to PageB and the book is selected appropriately.  But if you click on a link to PageA the *URL changes in the address bar*, but the controller function does not apparently run.  Similarly, on PageB, links to PageA will select a book, but links that stay on PageB do not.

I like the fact that the page is NOT re-read from the server ... it comes out of cache, but I would like to somehow trigger the the controller function again so that the new passed parameter can be read and the correct data displayed.  What am I doing wrong?

**Update One**

Some have suggested to add `target="_self"` to the hyperlink tag.   This works in the simplified minimal example above.  Unfortunately, it does not work on fully elaborated site.  I don't know why.  You can check the [full site](http://PurpleHillsBooks.com) and the problem is that the "Featured-Book" does not display if you are showing the details of any other book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It seems you need to use the `$location` service and `$locationChangeSuccess` event in order to keep track url changes. These are part of the Angular core API.

```
fooApp.controller('fooCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
   $scope.books = ["Book1", "Book2", "Book3", "Book4", "Book5"]
   $scope.selectedBook = "Book1";
   $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, location) {
      $scope.selectedBook = $location.path().substring(1);
   });
});
```

Comment: One notable detail: $location.path() has a URLDecoded version of the URI, which is a problem when the encoded data has slashes in it.

However, if I use window.location instead, the solution works perfectly.  Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to implement a route system. 
Have you looked into Angular's ngRoute? check out [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) example.

ngRoute is great because you can access route data via its $route service or simply via $routeParams.

Comment: Yes I have, no I don't want a route, and I don't want an SPA.   See [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/theproblemsolver/2013/10/23/to-spa-or-not-to-spa/).  Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633195/angularjs-route-parameters-with-any-characters).  However, if there is a trick from the route/location support that would trigger the Angular code on the change of the window location, I could use that.